# How to fetch emails found by instant search in Outlook using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, search, outlook

I use VBA to find email(s) by content of it's pdf attachment.

From what I understood, the only method without opening each email is Instant search.

I find the emails I look for. How do I work with emails that show as the result?

I didn't find how to save them to collection or something.

My search code:

```
Sub Search_Email()
Dim ol As Outlook.Application
Dim ns As Outlook.Namespace
Dim olFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim strFilter, txtSearch As String

Set ol = New Outlook.Application
Set ns = ol.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set olFolder = ns.Folders("RS Cash Application Inbox").Folders("Remittances")

Set ol.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder = olFolder

strFilter = "5860626494"

txtSearch = "attachment:" & strFilter

ol.ActiveExplorer.Search txtSearch, olSearchScopeCurrentFolder
End Sub
```

Result of the instant search. I need to download attachments from both displayed emails.
[image: screenshot]

Comment: `ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)` should return the first mail item after searching.

Comment: Thank you for reply. Yes, it does. However I can't return the second email as it's not selected. I need to be able to go through all returned emails.

Answer (score 1):

When calling `Search`, the query is run in the user interface, and there is no programmatic mechanism to obtain the search results. Also the `Search` method does not provide a callback to enable the developer to determine when the search is complete.

Instead, I'd suggest using the [AdvancedSearch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb219884.aspx) method of the `Application` class which provides the callback to get the results after. The key benefits of using the AdvancedSearch method in Outlook are:

- The search is performed in another thread. You don’t need to run another thread manually since the AdvancedSearch method runs it automatically in the background.
- Possibility to search for any item types: mail, appointment, calendar, notes etc. in any location, i.e. beyond the scope of a certain folder. The `Restrict` and `Find`/`FindNext` methods can be applied to a particular `Items` collection (see the `Items` property of the `Folder` class in Outlook).
- Full support for DASL queries (custom properties can be used for searching too). You can read more about this in the [Filtering](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208216%28v=office.12%29) article in MSDN. To improve the search performance, Instant Search keywords can be used if Instant Search is enabled for the store (see the `IsInstantSearchEnabled` property of the Store class).
- You can stop the search process at any moment using the `Stop` method of the Search class.

To retrieve the search results you need to handle the `AdvancedSearchComplete` event which is used to return the object that was created by the `AdvancedSearch` method. This event only fires when the `AdvancedSearch` method is executed programmatically.

```
Public blnSearchComp As Boolean

Private Sub Application_AdvancedSearchComplete(ByVal SearchObject As Search)
  MsgBox "The AdvancedSearchComplete Event fired."
  blnSearchComp = True
End Sub


Sub TestAdvancedSearchComplete()
  Dim sch As Outlook.Search
  Dim rsts As Outlook.Results
  Dim i As Integer
  blnSearchComp = False
  Const strF As String = "urn:schemas:mailheader:subject = 'Test'"
  Const strS As String = "Inbox"

  Set sch = Application.AdvancedSearch(strS, strF)

  While blnSearchComp = False
    DoEvents
  Wend

  Set rsts = sch.Results
  For i = 1 To rsts.Count
     MsgBox rsts.Item(i).SenderName
  Next
End Sub
```

After using the `Search` on the Outlook UI you can get access to the `CurrentView` by accessing corresponding properties on the `Explorer` object. The `View` class provides the [Filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.view.filter) property which returns a string value that represents the filter for a view. The value of this property is a string, in DAV Searching and Locating (DASL) syntax, that represents the current filter for the view. So, you can use it for the `AdvancedSearch` search string.

Comment: Hi Eugene, thank you for the elaborate answer. However, I can't find anywhere how to use Advanced Search to search inside of the attachments.

Comment: I am really basic level of knowledge so sorry my inadequacy. By "same search condition" I understood using "attachment:" condition? I came up with this:`Set srch = ol.AdvancedSearch("\\RS Cash Application Inbox\Remittances", "urn:schemas:httpmail:attachment =" & "'" & strFilter & "'")` but I get error "Something went wrong". Please could you be more specific how to use advanced search to search attachments? Thank you very much!

Comment: I've tried to add these two lines below the search in my code :   `Set olView = ActiveExplorer.CurrentView` and `Debug.Print olView.Filter`, but it returns empty string.

Comment: I found your post here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43874562/excel-vba-attachment-search,  where you say the Outlook object model doesn't have option to search strings inside the attachments. I couldn't find any reference to Advanced.Search being able to look into attachments neither, unfortunately. :(

Comment: You can find all items with attachments and then iterate over all of them saving the attachment on the disk and opening them programmatically to do the work. Also, you can access the attached files as a binary stream.

Comment: Thank you for your help so far, I appreciate it. Unfortunately, downloading all attachments is not an option as there are thousands of entries and it can't be done in time span I need. All I need at this point is to be able to open emails which I see in attached printscreen above. `ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)` work only for one email. If there is way how to select all displayed emails....    Thank you very much!